# why is my Gradle projects menu missing from android studio setting?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

when i go to the settings in android studio under build tools the Gradle menu which is generally there is missing([menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZfIq.png))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the `android` folder in your flutter application with Android Studio instead of the root folder.

Take a look

[image]